# AvoidXfermode on api v10 and api v14

Tags: android, android-canvas, xfermode

In map activity i created overlay on which on `Cnavas` i draw shapes using `Paint`

Shape consists from points and lines

```
linePaint = new Paint();
    linePaint.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.Line));
    linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    linePaint.setXfermode(avoidXfermode);
    linePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    mPointPaint = new Paint();
    mPointPaint.setColor(pointColor);
    mPointPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

Also I define `AvoidXfermode` to avoid points overlapping with lines (points must be "on top")

```
avoidXfermode = new AvoidXfermode(pointColor, 255, Mode.AVOID);
```

colors defined in resources in 32b format

```
<color name="Point">#FFFF0000</color>
<color name="Line">#FF4169E1</color>
```

The problem is: it works fine on devices with api 10, but it doesn't work at all under Nexus with api v14 (with any tolerance)

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AvoidXfermode is not supported with hardware acceleration.

You can determine that with View.isHardwareAccelerated() and set it with View.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_*). Although you might need to look for alternatives.

You can read about it here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported

Comment: Sometimes android fragmentation makes me cry)